# セレクトボックスを2つ選択してメッセージなどを表示するには

Tags: javascript, html5

セレクトボックスを2つ選択してメッセージなどを表示するには。～運賃検索プログラムを完成させたい～
次では、セレクトボックスで選択をすれば、メッセージが表示されるようになっています。

```
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function onButtonClick() {
      selindex = document.form1.Select1.selectedIndex;
      target = document.getElementById("output");
      switch (selindex) {
        case 0:
          target.innerHTML = "要素1が選択されています。<br/>";
          break;
        case 1:
          target.innerHTML = "要素2が選択されています。<br/>";
          break;
        case 2:
          target.innerHTML = "要素3が選択されています。<br/>";
          break;
        case 3:
          target.innerHTML = "要素4が選択されています。<br/>";
          break;
        case 4:
          target.innerHTML = "要素5が選択されています。<br/>";
          break;
      }
    }
  </script>
```

これと、組み合わせたいのが次のjsの文章です。どうしたらいいですか。

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function kotae()<br>
{
ten=0
if((f.q1.value == "松山市"&&f.q2.value == "高松市")||(f.q1.value == "高松市"&&f.q2.value == "松山市"))
{f.q1.style.backgroundColor="aqua ";ten = ten + 50}<br>
else f.q1.style.backgroundColor="red"
if(f.q3.value == "名古屋市"){f.q3.style.backgroundColor="aqua ";ten = ten + 25}<br>
else f.q3.style.backgroundColor="red"
if(f.q4.value == "金沢市") {f.q4.style.backgroundColor="aqua ";ten = ten + 25}<br>
else f.q4.style.backgroundColor="red"<br>
f.tokuten.value=ten
const keywords = ['あいうえお','かきくけこ', 'さしすせそ'];<br>
if (f.tokuten.value=50) {
    for (let i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++) {
        console.log(f.rank.value=keywords[0]);
    }}
else if(f.tokuten.value >=20){f.rank.value = 'B'}<br>
else if(f.tokuten.value >=15){f.rank.value = 'C'}<br>
else if(f.tokuten.value <10){f.rank.value = 'D'}<br>
//ここまで
}
</script>
<body>
<form name="f"><br>
愛媛県の県庁所在地は 
<select name="q1">
<option>選択肢</option>
<option>名古屋市</option>
<option>松山市</option>
<option>金沢市</option>
<option>高松市</option>
</select>
です。
<p>
香川県の県庁所在地は 
<select name="q2">
<option>選択肢</option>
<option>名古屋市</option>
<option>松山市</option>
<option>金沢市</option>
<option>高松市</option>
</select>
です。<p>
愛知県の県庁所在地は 
<select name="q3">
<option>選択肢</option>
<option>名古屋市</option>
<option>松山市</option>
<option>金沢市</option>
<option>高松市</option>
</select>
です。<p>
石川県の県庁所在地は 
<select name="q4">
<option>選択肢</option>
<option>名古屋市</option>
<option>松山市</option>
<option>金沢市</option>
<option>高松市</option>
</select>
です。<p>
<input type="button" name="b1" value="答え合わせ" onclick="kotae()"> <p>
<input name=tokuten size="6">点
<!--HTMLここから-->
<input name=rank class="hoge">ランク
<!--HTMLここまで-->
```

これらを組み合わせて、設問１と設問2でそれぞれ松山市と高松市を選択すればメッセージが表示されるようにしたいです。

Comment: 質問者の意図と異なる編集（`<br />` タグの扱い）が見られましたので、ロールバックしました。なお、質問者さんは Markdown を学習し、ソースコードはコードブロックとしてマークアップするようにして下さい。

Comment: @mjy "質問者の意図と異なる編集" が、具体的にどの行辺りかを詳しく教えてもらえますか？前後のリビジョンで「ソース」を比較しても、コード部分はインデントを調整しているだけのようです。直近でも似たような事例が発生していますが、編集者のミスだけでなく、サイト上のエディタやプレビュー機能に起因する問題の可能性も考えられます。

Comment: @cubick 少なくとも JavaScript の行末に `<br>` が出現してしまうのは、質問者の意図とは異なっています。
他にも意図とのズレは有るかも知れません。
編集合戦を避けるため、これ以上のロールバックはしませんが、本来はロールバックすべき状態です。
この現象の原因などに関しては、長くなるので、必要ならばメタで質問いただければと思います。

Comment: @mjy そういう意味では、3版より初版にロールバックしたうえでマークアップを修正するのが適切なのではないでしょうか？

Comment: @hinaloe なるほど、初版には整形目的のマークアップが無いんですね。だとすると、それが一番簡単ですね。

Comment: JavaScript 中の `<br>` タグは質問者自身が [リビジョン2](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/90138/revisions) で付け加えたもののように見ます。単にロールバックだけでなく、質問者本人にも意図したコードなのかを確認した方が確実な気がします。

Answer (score 1):

「`document.f.q1.value` が `"松山市"` かつ`document.f.q2.value` が `"高松市"` であればメッセージを表示する」という関数を `document.f.q1` と `document.f.q2` の `change` イベントリスナとして登録しましょう。